# How can i keep track of which randomly selected model was generated so it won't repeat again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code generated a random game object but because there are only 9 game objects sometimes the randomly generated object keeps re-generating more than one time. How can i restrict that, and have one game object generated only once ?

```
     public GameObject[] models;
     public static GameObject currentPoint;
     int index;
     public static string randomName;
     public AudioSource FindTheNumber;

public void PlayNumbers()
    {   


        models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("numbers");
        index = Random.Range (0,models.Length);
        currentPoint = models [index];
        randomName = currentPoint.name;
        print ("Trackable " + randomName);
        FindTheNumber.Play ();
        currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayDelayed(2);


    }
```

Comment: There should be a way to check if object is generated or not: a property of object class or a list holding generated object. Then you can check during generating if object is already generated and don't re-generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I will post the code I wrote so it may serve to someone in the future:

```
     public GameObject[] models;
     public static GameObject currentPoint;
     int index;
     public static string randomName;
     public AudioSource FindTheNumber;
     int i =9;

public void PlayNumbers()
    {   


       models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("numbers");
        if (i >= 0) 
        {
            index = i;
            currentPoint = models [index];
            randomName = currentPoint.name;
            print ("Trackable " + randomName);
            FindTheNumber.Play ();
            currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayDelayed (2);
            i--;
        } 
        else 
        {
            i=9;
            index = i;
            currentPoint = models [index];
            randomName = currentPoint.name;
            print ("Trackable " + randomName);
            FindTheNumber.Play ();
            currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayDelayed (2);
            i--;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, how about keeping track of the selected game objects in a separate list.

```
    public static List<GameObject> models;
    public static List<GameObject> selectedModels = new List<GameObject>();
    public static GameObject currentPoint;
    int index;
    public static string randomName;
    public AudioSource FindTheNumber;
    public static Random random = new Random();

    public void PlayNumbers()
    {   
        models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("numbers").Except(selectedModels).ToList();

        if ((models == null) || (!models.Any()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No new game objects");
        }
        else
        {
            index = random.Next(models.Count);
            currentPoint = models[index];
            randomName = currentPoint.name;
            print ("Trackable " + randomName);
            FindTheNumber.Play ();
            currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayDelayed(2);

            selectedModels.Add(currentPoint);
        }
}
```

Comment: Except, Next, ToList(), Any() are not recognized by Mono Develop

Comment: If you do `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file does it work?

Comment: Then replace random.Next with your implementation `Random.Range(0, models.Count);`. That way you wont have any hard coded indexes in your code like the solution you are using. Code reuse, and less duplication..

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that when you call currentPoint and create a sound for example you encounter the problem that the gameObject might get called more often creating the "same" object ?

If yes, you could save the last gameObject that was created and check if it is the same as the new one?

That way you always have a different gameObject every time ;). I don't know what's the delta between your calls and how long they last, but checking the gameObject should do the trick.

You could create a variable that stores information if the object is doing it's job.

Additionally you could check verify that the values differ from the gameObjects that are currently active.

Comment: can you post the code that checks this. If yes that would be very helpful :)

Comment: Sure, but i will post it later, i am not at home. Got no unity on this computer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correct your code should look something like this.

```
     public GameObject[] models;
 public static GameObject currentPoint;
 int index;
 public static string randomName;
 public AudioSource FindTheNumber;

 public void PlayNumbers()
 {   

    do {
      models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("numbers");
      index = Random.Range (0,models.Length);
      currentPoint = models [index];

   } while(currentPoint.getComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying);

   randomName = currentPoint.name;  
   print ("Trackable " + randomName);
   FindTheNumber.Play ();
   currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayDelayed(2);

 }
```

Right now the code will loop atleast one time. If the object you are trying to use is already playing the code will loop through the array again.
Once it finds a object that isn't playing the code will proceed and do what it should do.

If you get any errors or if my solution is incorrect just post again and tell us what you want (in detail)

Have a nice day ;)

PS: The only thing that annoys me is it might double check some values due to the Random.Range...

Comment: This line is giving an error : 
while(currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying());











 The member `UnityEngine.AudioSource.isPlaying' cannot be used as method or delegate

Comment: This is what I am trying to do (in details): To ensure that the user is not repeatedly prompted for the same models, I ought present the models in a randomized sequence/permutation, i.e., rather than picking models at random

Comment: The error was caused because isPlaying is called as isPlaying rather than isPlaying(). just remove the ().

Comment: This is working but I still get double checked values. This is what I am trying to do: 
To ensure that the user is not repeatedly prompted for the same models, I ought present the models in a randomized sequence/permutation, i.e., rather than picking models at random

Comment: Well then check where the prompt happens. It shouldn't happen if the value that you get by your random sequence is active / playing. The method of thinking is the same. Just place the verification somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to the recommendation Vancold.at made

```
public void PlayNumbers()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("numbers");
    while (true)
    {
        index = rnd.Next(0, models.Length - 1);
        var newPoint = models[index];

        //assumes currentPoint is initially null the first time this method is called
        if(currentPoint == null || newPoint.name != currentPoint.name)
        { 
            currentPoint = newPoint;
            break;
        }
    }
    randomName = currentPoint.name;
    print("Trackable " + randomName);
    FindTheNumber.Play();
    currentPoint.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayDelayed(2);
}
```

Keep in mind that this only assures the same GameObject instance isn't used two times in a row. It will not prevent same object from being used more than once. For example, if you have 9 GameObject instances with names "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", the code above allows the following output:

```
Trackable 5
Trackable 7
Trackable 5
Trackable 4
Trackable 7
```

Etc. If you want to cycle through the possible values once before repeating, then a different approach is needed.